# Complex numbers argument

Tags: complex-numbers

**Question:**

> $$z=\frac{a+3i}{2+ai}$$
>
> Show that there is only one value of $a$ for which $\operatorname{arg} z= \frac{\pi}{4}$, and find this value.

**My attempt:**
$$\frac{a+3i}{2+ai}\cdot\frac{2-ai}{2-ai}$$
$$=\frac {5a+(6-a^2)i}{4+a^2}$$
$$=\frac {5a}{4+a^2}+\frac {6-a^2}{4+a^2}i$$
$$\tan(\pi/4)=\frac {\mathrm{opposite}}{\mathrm{adjacent}}$$
$$\tan(\pi/4)=\frac{\frac{6-a^2}{4+a^2}}{\frac{5a}{4+a^2}}$$

**My Questions:**

1) at the last point of my working $$\tan(\pi/4)=\frac{\frac{6-a^2}{4+a^2}}{\frac{5a}{4+a^2}}$$ the [answer of the book](http://i45.tinypic.com/xf6r9u.png) shows it the other way around like this:
$$\tan(\pi/4)=\frac{\frac{5a}{4+a^2}}{\frac{6-a^2}{4+a^2}}$$
Why? Since I use $\tan(\theta)=\mathrm{opp}/\mathrm{adj}$, opposite would be the y-value or imaginary and adjacent the x-value and real.

2) The book states no reason for why we multiply by the complex conjugate and I would like to learn why

Comment: Not surprising that the person got careless, we will get $5a=6-a^2$ in any case, since $1/\tan(\pi/4)=\tan(\pi/4)$. We multiply by the complex conjugate to get the number in "standard form" $c+di$ from which the argument can be read off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Your answer is correct, but technically, the answer in the book is correct as well, since $\tan \pi/4 = 1$.

Question 2: Multiplying by the complex conjugate of the denominator helps you get rid of the imaginary numbers in there, since $(a+ib)(a-ib) = a^2 + b^2$.

**Edit:** The answer in the book is misleading.

Comment: I understood about the conjugate pair, but I didn't get 'The angle is measured from the real axis'. You mean that x is the imaginary axis and y is the real-axis in that case? In any case where did that come from?

Comment: No, I did not mean that. What I meant was that the angle is measured going anti-clockwise from the $x$ axis, which is also the real axis. If you draw a picture, you will see what I mean.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still do not understand, could you elaborate with a graph? (this is what I am currently thinking http://i47.tinypic.com/2wevvus.png)

Comment: Actually, you are right - I somehow got confused reading your question.

Comment: Marking this as accepted, conclusion is that the book is most likely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this image helps clear up the confusion :)

[image]

Note: Your book probably made a typo. Your answer is correct.

Comment: Actually, this is what the question describes; the book somehow deviates from this!?

Comment: I am afraid so. Your answer is correct.

Comment: Do you think it is safe to assume that the book is wrong?/

Comment: It's quite likely.

Comment: You often find 1 or 2 mistakes in exercise books